# Sprite not moving on JPanel

Tags: java, sprite, keylistener

I'm trying to get a simple sprite moving around my screen. I can't get my head around what is wrong with this code as i've followed instructions from a different source code but removed some complexity added from other features in other code.
Right now I'm just trying to get it to move around freely on the screen.
Later I intend for the animation to change while its moving.
Code for both classes is below.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer:

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

int x, y, b_width, b_height;
Player player;
      Timer timer;

public Game() {
    addKeyListener(new KeyRecorder());
    player = new Player();

                timer = new Timer(5, this);
                timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(player.image, player.getX(), player.getY(), this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    player.move();
    repaint();
}

public class KeyRecorder extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        player.keyPressed(e);
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        player.keyReleased(e);
    }
}

}
```

And the sprite:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {

private String sprite = "sprite.png"; 
int x, y, dx, dy;
int width, height;
Image image;

public Player() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(sprite));
    image = ii.getImage();

}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public void move() {
    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dy -= 3;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dy += 3;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx -= 3;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dx += 3;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
             int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dy -= 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dy += 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx -= 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        dx += 0;
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method.

KeyEvents are only received by comonents with focus. It doesn't look like you panel has focus. In the constructor you need to add:

```
setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: so, just so we're clear, should I have changed the paint() method to "@Override paintComponent(Graphics g){}" ? if so, it didn't work. I've added the setFocusable in the constructor too

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but you are overriding the wrong method!!! paintComponent() is where you should be adding your custom painting logic. You should also have a super.paintComponent() at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a huge amount about swing, but are you calling "repaint()" for every frame you want drawn? For example

```
thePanel.repaint();
```

If it flickers, you may also want to set the panel to double buffered

```
setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

I hope those helps you anyway. If that doesn't answer your question, perhaps this will http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ I don't have time to read through it but I did skim it and it looks good.

Comment: Yeah, I have it to repaint every time a key is pressed. Thanks, I'll take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? does the sprite draw once and not move after that or not draw at all?

Comment: Sorry I admit I didn't quite look at the code as much as I should have initially, and as camickr said it might be that your panel doesn't have focus. Have you tried setting a breakpoint for actionperformed to see if the method is actually ever called?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I didn't say in my original post..It draws fine, but it won't respond to the keys

Comment: I forgot to re-add the timer into the constructor that's in the original code, i've added it and its now calling actionPerformed but still no movement.

Comment: I've figured something out, I have another class which just had a JMenuBar and a JFrame included, I have removed the JMenuBar and the sprite is now moving